# Conan: How to get the source folder of a dependency from within `conanfile.py`?

Tags: cmake, configuration, conan

I want to create a conan wrapper over a project's sources that can be downloaded.
Note that I cannot modify anything in that project; I am just given a URL from where it can be downloaded.

I know how to download and uncompressed the project's sources (using the `tools` module) by adding some code in the `source()` method in the `conanfile.py`.

That project (once downloaded and uncompressed) can be built with cmake and can use Boost.
So I added `boost/1.75` in `build_requires` (I chose the version arbitrarily).
In the cmake's configuration phase of that project, it is possible to pass the Boost's location folder as an argument to cmake (e.g. `-DWITH_BOOST=path_name`).

But from within the `build()` method, I don't how to get the folder where Boost 1.75 is installed in the conan cache. Knowing that, I would then pass it to the `cmake.configure(...)` call.

Is there a way to get the package folder of a dependency from within `conanfile.py`? Perhaps by using something like `self.build_requires['boost/1.75'].package_folder`?

Comment: You don't need to pass source folder. As you are using CMake, Conan can generate [cmake](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake.html), [cmake_paths](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_paths_generator.html), [cmake_find_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html) which find all headers for you.

Comment: According to you, conan will automatically add `-DWITH_BOOST=boost_dependency_path` magically to the cmake configuration of a sourced project it does know anything about?

Comment: It will add, if the recipe is prepared to do it, and if you use a helper which passes all cmake defines, including that you mentioned. The cmake wrappers are those that I commented before. If you want to see the cmake command executed by Conan, you can set the env var [CONAN_PRINT_RUN_COMMANDS](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-print-run-commands).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get dependency path is:

```py
from conans import ConanFile # for type hinting

# conan create
boost: ConanFile = self.dependencies.build["boost"]
boost.package_folder
```

but it will **not work always**:

- `self.dependencies` is none when dependency tree is not evaluated, for example during `conan build` https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/10535 you can use this hacky workaround:

```py
# conan build (hacky)
self.deps_cpp_info["boost"].build_paths[0]
```

- it might not be available in all steps (I did not check in detail)

The most reliable way to get this information is actually to read if from `conanbuildinfo.txt` - this file is created during install step, you can use different generators, like `-g json` to use it in different formats.
You can read this file using conan api:

```py
from conans.client.generators import TXTGenerator
with open("conanbuildinfo.txt", "r") as handle:
    contents = handle.read()
deps_cpp_info, deps_user_info, deps_env_info, user_info_build = TXTGenerator.loads(contents)
```

And the last way that I found in my code (this can be simplified, but that is what I can provide for now):

```py
import sys

import conans.errorsc
import conans.cli.exit_codes
from conans import ConanFile

from conans.client.cache.cache import ClientCache
from conans.client.conan_api import Conan
from conans.model.ref import PackageReference
from conans.paths.package_layouts.package_editable_layout import PackageEditableLayout

try:
    conan_api, _, _ = Conan.factory()
except conans.errors.ConanMigrationError:
    sys.exit(conans.cli.exit_codes.ERROR_MIGRATION)
except conans.errors.ConanException as error:
    sys.exit(conans.cli.exit_codes.ERROR_GENERAL)


def _discover_package_path(dependency_name: str) -> str:
    """Returns a package folder in local conan cache for specified dependency.
    Function is similar to:
    > conan info conanfile.py --paths --only package_folder
    This implementation is based on _grab_info_data (Conan version 1.55.0-dev):
    >>> from conans.client.conan_command_output import CommandOutputer
    >>> CommandOutputer._grab_info_data
    """
    data, _ = conan_api.info(reference_or_path="conanfile.py")
    node = next(node for node in data.nodes if node.name == dependency_name)
    cache = ClientCache(conan_api.cache_folder, conan_api.out)
    layout = cache.package_layout(node.ref, node.conanfile.short_paths)
    if isinstance(layout, PackageEditableLayout):
        return node.conanfile.package_folder
    else:
        return layout.package(PackageReference(node.ref, node.package_id))


# _discover_package_path("cmake")

class MyDummy(ConanFile):
    name = "MyDummy"
    version = "0.0.1"
    requires = "boost/1.71.0"

    def build(self):
        print(80 * "#")
        print(_discover_package_path("boost"))
        print(80 * "#")
```